# ¿Como ejecutar método asíncrono en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un método asíncrono definido en mi lógica de negocios mediante TPL que me permite obtener un listado de 5000 productos de una base de datos con el siguiente código.

```
 public async Task ProductList() {
      await this.ProductServices.ListAsync();
 }
```

Al mandar a cargar un formulario hago la llamada al método asíncrono dentro del evento `Form_Load` pero este no llena el Grid con los datos como debería hacer `ProductList` depurando note que no entra al método asíncrono.

El código donde lo llamo es este:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      this.ProductList();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te faltan 2 detalles:

1. Agregar el modificador `async` a la declaración del método `Form1_Load`.
2. Hacerle un `await` a la llamada `this.ProductList()`.

Código:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await this.ProductList();
}
```

Ojo que, aunque la llamada es asíncrona, o sea que libera el UI thread mientras se cargan tus productos, eso no cambia el hecho que la ventana no va a terminar de cargarse hasta que complete la ejecución del método `ProductList`. En otras palabras, no esperes que puedas ver la ventana hasta que termine de ejecutar `ProductList`.

Si esto no es lo que quieres, probablemente debas ejecutar `ProductList` dentro de otro event handler mas adecuado a tus necesidades.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón ese era el problema. Ahora si carga los datos @sstan

Answer (score 0):

Para llamar el método asíncrono dentro del evento `Load` debes usar también la palabra clave `async` en el `Form_Load` y `await` para llamar al método. Quizás ahí esté el problema.

```
 private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      await this.ProductList();
 }
```